# Change mongoose query array to a string while using NodeJS, MongoDB, and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a query in my mongoose schema which displays this in a resultArray

```
[
  { scholarship_type: 'Archer Achiever Scholarship' },
  { scholarship_type: 'Star Scholarship' },
  { scholarship_type: 'Star Scholarship' },
  { scholarship_type: 'Archer Achiever Scholarship' },
  { scholarship_type: 'Star Scholarship' },
  { scholarship_type: 'Archer Achiever Scholarship' }
]
```

I would like to convert this array to a substring which is

"Archer Achiever Scholarship, Star Scholarship, Star Scholarship, Archer Achiever Scholarship, Star Scholarship, Archer Achiever Scholarship"

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this in js:
By using .map(), we iterate over the objects, and return the scholarship_type property. This gives us an array of strings containing the scholarship_type properties.

```
const scholarshipObjects = [{ scholarship_type: 'Archer Achiever Scholarship' },/*...*/]

const scholarshipsList = scholarshipObjects.map(
    (scholarship) => scholarship.scholarship_type
);
```